# Python 3 method parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning Python 3. I came across below code.

```
class Calculator:
    def addition(x,y,):
        print(x+y)
    def multiplication(x,y):
        print(x*y)

print(Calculator.addition(5,5))
```

And it prints `10`

Why it doesn't give syntax error for the extra comma in `addition(x,y,)` ? method. Why it worked ?

Comment: Python allows it, the comma has no meaning, so why would that need to be a syntax error?

Comment: It works because a trailing comma is permitted by [the language specification](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions). Why the specification permits it, is a matter of speculation. Only the BDFL can know for sure ;-)

Comment: It looks inconsistent in the first exposure. By the way why meaningless commas are allowed ?